# Retrieve subscribers who haven't opened an email in over 5 years

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I know the Data Views only go back 6 months. How can I find subscribers who haven't opened an email in over 5 years? I know how to use the API, but I'm not sure how to use it to find this. I can pull open events and send events, but how can I pull subscribers and find out if they have opens in the past 5 years? I know how I'd do it with a Query, but not sure how I can do this with the PHP api.

Comment: Best bet is opening a ticket to have MC Support do this for you

Comment: I opened a ticket, but if someone as a general guideline wanted to walk me through how to get this with the API, I'm open to it

Comment: I don't think there is a way through API alone, you would likely need to do Data Extracts (3 month max each pull) and then combine this data (recommend in a SQL server or similar DB environment) then query and combine in there to get your info.

Comment: But can data extracts go past 6 months @Gortonington ?

Comment: So i tried this for 2012 and the files were empty. I'm assuming that's too far back :(

Comment: Ok I must have been doing something wrong because it started working. I haven't tried 2012, but I was able to get 2015. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It should go back as far as the beginning of your subscription contract.  I have only found a 90 day option (and documentation says it only goes to 30)https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/create_a_data_extract_file/